# I am connected to the internet but can not use it

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Recently my OS has gone mad. I am connected to the internet, able to ping, nslookup, update and so on from the terminal, but unable to browse or use the applications that might require connection. Also I noticed that my network adapters' name also changed from eth0 and wlan0 to enp9s0 and wlp8s0.
Can anyone please help me, I really do not want to reinstall the Linux

Comment: This is a change in Ubuntu that now uses the "Predictable interface names." Can you run ethtool on interface enp9s0 and post the results. i believe it would just be: ethtool enp9s0  Maybe throw a sudo in there if it doesnt work.

Comment: What errors are you experiencing? Can you ping and URL or only IP addresses?

Comment: enp9s0 and wlp8s0 indicate switching to systemd's predictable naming scheme for network interfaces. So knowing OS version would be nice. Just a guess but do you have firewall that may be blocking the traffic ?

Comment: @jwcooper I can only post camera picture due to the problem here's the link: http://www.kepfeltoltes.eu/view.php?filename=91220190426_214833.jpg

Comment: I am able to ping urls too, also I do have basic linux fire wall, but I was bot bothering it

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at work so your pic is blocked by the network. The firewall you mentioned. Is it UFW or iptables or something else?

Comment: @jwcooper sorry 'bout the pic. I am not much of a linux wizard (yet), I think it is just ip tables, but I've downloaded a gui version too, it is just shows me the firewall configurations.

Comment: No problem. Try this to find out iptables status: sudo iptables -L -n -v

Comment: Also, try this: sudo ufw disable  If that works, then that was your problem and we can start trying to fix it. If not, we will keep chipping away at it.

Comment: @jwcooper I do have some rules in my iptable but they are all by default except that I opened the 9000 port for tcp and udp, but it was a long time ago, I do not think that this could cause the problem. I also stopped the firewall with ufw disable command

Comment: What OS/version are you running? We only support Ubuntu here.

Comment: @heynnema I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS